# Hiding a radio button option

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have a selection of `radio buttons` and I want it so the if the user `clicks` on "Highest calling costs" then it `hides` the "Select by cost" Radio buttons.

**Code for reference:**

```html
 <div id="radioGroup">
    
    <h3>Select by Amount: </h3>
     <input type="radio" name="dialinfo" value="mostdialled"> <label for="mostdialled">Most Dialled Digits</label><br>
     <input type="radio" name="dialinfo" value="highestcost"> <label for="highestcost">Highest Costing Calls</label>
    
    <br>
    
    <h3>Select by Location: </h3>
     <input type="radio" name="callLocation"> <label for="callLocation">Inside the UK</label><br>
     <input type="radio" name="callLocation"> <label for="callLocation">International</label>
    
    
    <h3>Select by Cost: </h3>
     <input type="radio" name="costradio"> <label for="costradio">Less than &pound;1</label><br>
     <input type="radio" name="costradio"> <label for="costradio">More than &pound;1</label><br>
     <input type="radio" name="costradio"> <label for="costradio">More than &pound;5</label><br>
     <input type="radio" name="costradio"> <label for="costradio">More than &pound;10</label>
    
    
    <h3>Select Duration: </h3>
     <input type="radio" name="callDuration"> <label for="callDuration">Less than 60s</label><br>
     <input type="radio" name="callDuration"> <label for="callDuration">More than 60s</label><br>
     <input type="radio" name="callDuration"> <label for="callDuration">More than 1hr</label><br>
     <input type="radio" name="callDuration"> <label for="callDuration">More than 5hrs</label>
    </div>
```

Thank you,

Sean

Answer (score 2):

i've added divs so i can identify the areas and trigger the jquery with the change function

Try the following:

```js
$("#radioGroup #select_amount input").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "highestcost") {
    $("#select_cost").hide();
  } else {
    $("#select_cost").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="radioGroup">

  <div id="select_amount">
    <h3>Select by Amount: </h3>
    <input type="radio" name="dialinfo" value="mostdialled">
    <label for="mostdialled">Most Dialled Digits</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="dialinfo" value="highestcost">
    <label for="highestcost">Highest Costing Calls</label>
  </div>
  <br>

  <h3>Select by Location: </h3>
  <input type="radio" name="callLocation">
  <label for="callLocation">Inside the UK</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="callLocation">
  <label for="callLocation">International</label>

  <div id="select_cost">
    <h3>Select by Cost: </h3>
    <input type="radio" name="costradio">
    <label for="costradio">Less than &pound;1</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="costradio">
    <label for="costradio">More than &pound;1</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="costradio">
    <label for="costradio">More than &pound;5</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="costradio">
    <label for="costradio">More than &pound;10</label>
  </div>

  <h3>Select Duration: </h3>
  <input type="radio" name="callDuration">
  <label for="callDuration">Less than 60s</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="callDuration">
  <label for="callDuration">More than 60s</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="callDuration">
  <label for="callDuration">More than 1hr</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="callDuration">
  <label for="callDuration">More than 5hrs</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, yeah this is perfect, works fine on JSfiddle but not on my page for some reason, I'll figure that out but thank you very much for the help!

Comment: try to add  the jquery code into $(document).ready(function(){ .. }

Answer (score 1):

Just try this.,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[name="dialinfo"]').on('change', function(){
     var val = $(this).val();
    //alert(val);
  if(val == "highestcost"){
    $('input[name="costradio"]').eq(0).prev('h3').hide();
    $('input[name="costradio"]').next('label').hide();
    $('input[name="costradio"]').hide();    
    }
    else{
    $('input[name="costradio"]').eq(0).prev('h3').show();
    $('input[name="costradio"]').next('label').show();
    $('input[name="costradio"]').show();    
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="radioGroup">

<h3>Select by Amount: </h3>
    <input type="radio" name="dialinfo" value="mostdialled"> <label for="mostdialled">Most Dialled Digits</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="dialinfo" value="highestcost"> <label for="highestcost">Highest Costing Calls</label>

<br>

<h3>Select by Location: </h3>
    <input type="radio" name="callLocation"> <label for="callLocation">Inside the UK</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="callLocation"> <label for="callLocation">International</label>


<h3>Select by Cost: </h3>
    <input type="radio" name="costradio"> <label for="costradio">Less than &pound;1</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="costradio"> <label for="costradio">More than &pound;1</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="costradio"> <label for="costradio">More than &pound;5</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="costradio"> <label for="costradio">More than &pound;10</label>


<h3>Select Duration: </h3>
    <input type="radio" name="callDuration"> <label for="callDuration">Less than 60s</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="callDuration"> <label for="callDuration">More than 60s</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="callDuration"> <label for="callDuration">More than 1hr</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="callDuration"> <label for="callDuration">More than 5hrs</label>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great, leaves a small space but I can deal with that! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could bind event on change for radio group and then do your stuff on condition -

```
$('input[type=radio][name=dialinfo]').change(function() {
            if (this.value == 'highestcost') {
                $('input[type=radio][name=costradio]').hide();
            }
            else {
            $('input[type=radio][name=costradio]').show();
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you want something like **[this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOWKEP)**?

It depends what you exactly want to happen, then the code can be changed

```
 <div id="radioGroup">

   <div id="amount-group">
    <h3>Select by Amount: </h3>
        <input type="radio" name="dialinfo" value="mostdialled" id='mostdialled'> <label for="mostdialled">Most Dialled Digits</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="dialinfo" value="highestcost" id='highestcost'> <label for="highestcost">Highest Costing Calls</label>
   </div>
<br>

<h3>Select by Location: </h3>
    <input type="radio" name="callLocation"> <label for="callLocation">Inside the UK</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="callLocation"> <label for="callLocation">International</label>


<h3>Select by Cost: </h3>
    <input type="radio" name="costradio"> <label for="costradio">Less than &pound;1</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="costradio"> <label for="costradio">More than &pound;1</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="costradio"> <label for="costradio">More than &pound;5</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="costradio"> <label for="costradio">More than &pound;10</label>


<h3>Select Duration: </h3>
    <input type="radio" name="callDuration"> <label for="callDuration">Less than 60s</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="callDuration"> <label for="callDuration">More than 60s</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="callDuration"> <label for="callDuration">More than 1hr</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="callDuration"> <label for="callDuration">More than 5hrs</label>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#amount-group').click(function() {
    if ($('#mostdialled').is(':checked') || $('#highestcost').is(':checked')) {
      $('#amount-group').slideUp(1000);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Hi, no I want the amount group to stay, but if the user selects "highest cost  " in that group, I want the "select by cost" to disappear .